# Rails: Validate uniqueness with scope, without self referential associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a relationship similar to this:

```
class Cat
  belongs_to :owner
  has_one :pet, class_name: "Cat", foreign_key: "pet_id"
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :owner_id }
end

class Owner
  has_many :cats
end
```

I would like each `Cat` that belongs to an `Owner` to have a unique name. For example, Bob and John (two owners) can both own a cat named Bill, however John cannot own two cats named Bill. Also, I want the cat named Bill to be able to own a cat named Bill. This is tricky because both Bill's are an instance of the Cat model and both have a owner_id. How would I make the name be unique on the Cat level immediately under Owner **only**?

Answer (score 0):

A polymorphic assocation should work

```
class AddOwnableToCats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cats, :ownable_id, :integer
    add_column :cats, :ownable_type, :string
    add_index :cats, [:ownable_type, :ownable_id]
  end
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
  has_one :pet, class_name: 'Cat', as: :ownable
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [:ownable_id, :ownable_type] }
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cats, as: ownable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom validation:

```
# Cat.rb

  # this line of code was here
  has_one :cat, class_name: "Cat", foreign_key: "parent_id"

  validates_each :name do |record, attr, value|
    similar = Cat.where.not(id: record.id, parent_id: record.id).where(attr => value, owner_id: record.owner_id)
    record.errors.add(attr, 'already exists') unless similar.empty?
  end
```